# could not prepare statement (1 misuse of aggregate function COUNT())

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
select U.userEmail, U.firstname + ' ' + U.surName as fullname 
from tblUser as U inner join tblHitchhhiker as H on U.userEmail= H.userEmail
left outer join tblGetAsk as G  on H.userEmail = G.userEmail
where COUNT(G.userEmail) = 0
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 misuse of aggregate function
> COUNT())

What I'm actually want to do is: Select only users that are also an hitchhiker and that have 0 records in tblGetAsk.

Comment: Which DBMS is this? Please tag it appropriately.

Comment: `Select only users that are also an hitchhiker and that have 0 records in tblGetAsk`...try a `NOT IN` query

Comment: @ADyson online SQL Tryit Editor of W3Schools

Comment: @ADyson will this work?: select U.userEmail, U.firstname + ' ' + U.surName as fullname 
from tblUser as U inner join tblHitchhhiker as H on U.userEmail= H.userEmail
where U.userEmail not in (select userEmail from tblGetAsk)

Comment: `online SQL Tryit Editor of W3Schools`...for which database system? It has courses for various different SQL variants.

Comment: `will this work`...the fastest way to discover that is to test it. But it looks plausible, yes.

Comment: I don't know for each database system it's tuned. Ideally it should run on SQL Server.

Comment: I just clicked on the `?` under the editor which is linked from the main page of their principal SQL course and it explains that it uses WebSQL. As long as you stick to writing standard ANSI-compliant SQL (which your suggested query in the comments appears to) you should have no issues, but be aware that each SQL system has its own syntax differences, function names and other quirks as you get into more complex situations. I think their tutorial should make that clearer...w3schools has many issues as a learning platform, it often contains mistakes / bad practices / oversimplifications sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...have 0 records in tblGetAsk

This means that there is no matching row in `tblGetAsk` for that `userEmail` of `tblUser`, so your condition should be `where G.userEmail IS NULL`:

```
select U.userEmail, U.firstname + ' ' + U.surName as fullname 
from tblUser as U 
inner join tblHitchhhiker as H on U.userEmail= H.userEmail
left outer join tblGetAsk as G on U.userEmail = G.userEmail
where G.userEmail IS NULL
```

You could also use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` instead of the joins:

```
select U.userEmail, U.firstname + ' ' + U.surName as fullname 
from tblUser as U 
where exists (select 1 from tblHitchhhiker as H where H.userEmail= U.userEmail)
  and not exists (select 1 from tblGetAsk as G where G.userEmail = U.userEmail)
```

Comment: Thanks you. Any chance you can also take a look at this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68503998/could-not-prepare-statement-1-misuse-of-aggregate-function-count-part-2