# could not prepare statement (1 misuse of aggregate function COUNT()) - part 2

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
select U1.userEmail, U1.firstname + ' ' + U1.surName as fullname 
from tblUser as U1 inner join tblDriver as D on U1.userEmail= D.userEmail
inner join tblGetAsk as GA  on GA.userEmail = D.userEmail
where not exists (select 1 from tblRideRating as R where R.userEmail = U1.userEmail)
and count(GA.userEmail) >= 3
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 misuse of aggregate function
> COUNT())

What I'm actually want to do is: Select only users who are also a driver and have 0 records in tblRideRating, and have at least 3 records in tblGetAsk.

Comment: The concatenation operator `+` that you use works in SQL Server, but the error message seems to be SQLite. Which database do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.
Group by user and use a `HAVING` clause:

```
select U1.userEmail, U1.firstname + ' ' + U1.surName as fullname 
from tblUser as U1 
inner join tblDriver as D on D.userEmail= U1.userEmail
inner join tblGetAsk as GA on GA.userEmail = U1.userEmail
where not exists (select 1 from tblRideRating as R where R.userEmail = U1.userEmail)
group by U1.userEmail, U1.firstname + ' ' + U1.surName
having count(GA.userEmail) >= 3
```

If you have duplicate emails for each user in `tblGetAsk`, maybe you should change to:

```
having count(distinct GA.userEmail) >= 3
```

You could also aggregate in `tblGetAsk` and then join:

```
select U1.userEmail, U1.firstname + ' ' + U1.surName as fullname 
from tblUser as U1 
inner join tblDriver as D on D.userEmail= U1.userEmail
inner join (
  select userEmail
  from tblGetAsk
  group by userEmail
  having count(*) >= 3 
) as GA on GA.userEmail = U1.userEmail
where not exists (select 1 from tblRideRating as R where R.userEmail = U1.userEmail)
```

Comment: But I don't really need to group here anything. There's no other way?

Comment: @Alon you can get the number of emails only with aggregation. I placed the aggregation in the main query. I could place it in the table tblGetAsk. See my edited answer.